# Eclipse: Move to a new line via shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently moved to Eclipse. In Visual Studio there is a shortcut <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> where I go to a new line no matter where I am in the code (in the middle of a line, close to the beginning/end of a line,...).

Is there such a shortcut in Eclipse? I can't find it in the list of shortcuts.

PS. I am not sure if the mentioned shortcut is Visual Studio native shortcut or it's ReSharper's shortcut.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> enter line below current line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> enter line above current line